# Mac Mail V10 - What happens if I delete all Attachments folders?

Tags: macos, mail.app

What happens if I hard delete all Attachments folders that reside under `~/myUser/Library/Mail/V10`? my expectation is that the recent ones are able to be redownloaded from the server and mail will do it automatically

Comment: What problem do you have that you think doing this might solve? Might be better to start your question with that. Sounds like you have an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I have over 19gb of mail and I need local storage...